# JMeter : how to use the timestamp of the parent

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing a group of urls for performance tests. We have an SLA that states that a certain group of URLS must have an average of 80% success within a certain timerange.
The logic of the sla is done in a separate application. The data is fed from JMeter output into a database.

I need a way to identify the 5 tests of these urls, so that the application knows they belong to the same test. I use a Transaction Controller to group all the URL tests, but I still don't see how I can put an identifier in the generated output file (done by View Results Tree Listener). If I could reuse the timestamp of the parent, i.e. the Transaction Controller for the individual HTTP Requests, that would make my day. I tried adding User Defined Variables under the Transaction Controller, but I don't see how I can output the value of my variable into the output file.

Is anything similar possible?

Best regards,
Wim

Comment: Did you find answer to your question ? Please gve feedback ...

Answer (score 0):

Store your value in jmeter context using a Beanshell sampler then in jeter.properties uncomment sample_variables ans add the name under which you stored your value:

## Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.

## Use commas to separate the names. For example:

## sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE

Regards

Philippe M.